# Database update using wpDataTables plugin

Tags: wordpress

I am creating a database application containing information about all the banks in Germany. I'm using phpmyadmin for the back end and wordpress for the front end. I am planning to install wpDataTables plugin to be able to display tables from my MySQL database on my web page. Is it possible to insert into/update my database from the front end using this plugin? Is it possible to make the entires in the table clickable (so that on clicking the entry, it goes to another page containing details about that entry)?
P.S. I am new to web development and wordpress and it would be great to get some help to solve this problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. It is possible to make wpDataTables created from MySQL query editable. You can take a look at their documentation page at this [link](https://wpdatatables.com/documentation/front-end-editing/creating-editable-tables/). There is a limitation if you are using JOIN in MySQL query and tables like this can't be editable.

> Only one MySQL table can be edited at a time. Queries from multiple tables with joins cannot be used for editable feature, since SQL UPDATE and INSERT statements are generated automatically, and for now there is no way to update multiple tables – but we are working on this.

2. With built-in features it is not possible to create clickable rows. Something like that would probably require some custom coding.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answers @priyanka and @ Diego. Things are working pretty well with wpdatatables now. Also found another plugin-woocommerce which can be used for the same purpose . :)